# Temporize Addon's Cron Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cron

I'm trying out Heroku's Temporize Add-on and am having trouble interacting with their recurring API. Any help would be appreciated!

When I make a POST request to create a new recurring task, I receive the following message: "failed to parse either date or cron expression".

Unfortunately I get this message with every cron statement I try, even the one used in their example. To make matters worse, the API endpoint they list on their website is different than what they list in their API docs "/events/cron/url" vs "/events/when/cron/url".

Some cron statements I've tried:

- 0 12 * * * *
- 0 0 12 1/1 * ? *
- 15 * * * * *

The code and cron syntax I'm using is similar to what they use on their website but I'll post it here just in case. For what it's worth the "single task" endpoint works as expected. Hopefully I'm just doing something silly...

Links: 
http://www.temporize.net; http://docs.temporize.apiary.io

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'cgi'
require 'time'

class Temporize
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://api.temporize.net/v1"
  attr_accessor :credentials

  def initialize
    uri = URI(ENV["TEMPORIZE_URL"])
    self.credentials = {:username => uri.user, :password => uri.password}
  end

  # Schedule a test event to run right away
  def single(callback_url, date = Time.now.utc.iso8601)
    url = CGI::escape(callback_url)
    Temporize.post("/events/#{date}/#{url}", :basic_auth => self.credentials)
  end

  # Schedule a test event to run on a schedule
  def recurring(callback_url, cron_schedule)
    cron = CGI::escape(cron_schedule) # ex "5 10 * * ?"
    url = CGI::escape(callback_url)
    Temporize.post("/events/#{cron}/#{url}", :basic_auth => self.credentials)
  end
end

t = Temporize.new
t.recurring("http://example.com/callback", "0 12 * * * *")
# => Result: failed to parse either date or cron expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, cron syntax, the syntax is:

```
<minutes> <hours> <day of month> <month> <day of week>
```

All of your examples have 6 fields, not 5. Double check to ensure you have 5 space-separated fields for your cron syntax.

Comment: Doesn't help. `test` and `auth` work but not `recurring`